# Ensuring unique keys in Exception.Data IDictionary

Tags: c#, exception, anonymous-types, idictionary

I have written an extension method to help with collecting crash data during error reporting.  This method is designed to ensure that a key is always unique.  If you have a few try/catch blocks, sometimes data can get duplicated.  I'm going for reasonably easy here, not super-best practices.

The problem: changing the key if it isn't unique.  When I try the below, method, I get "cannot convert from 'string' to 'TKey'".  Any ideas?

```
    public static void AddUnique<TKey, TValue>(this System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if(dictionary[key] != null)
        {
            var newKey = key.ToString() + "-";
            AddUnique<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, newKey, value);
        }               

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your keys will always be strings, then remove the `TKey` generic parameter from the method signature, and just use `string` in its place. Alternatively, you may want to keep both generic parameters, but change the recursive call to `AddUnique<string, TValue>()`.

Comment: Excellent idea.  It seems so obvious.  So could I have a method like AddUniqueInner(System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary, string key, object value)?  That would save the TValue, right?

Comment: Since strings are probably the best idea for keys, I would just make the signature `AddUnique<TValue>(this IDictionary dict, string key, TValue value)`

Comment: That kills the extension method though, doesn't it?  That doesn't match the signature of Exception.Data.Add.

Comment: No, it's still fine. The compiler knows that `TValue` will always be convertible to `object`, so the add should still work. Given that you're working with the non-generic `IDictionary`, though, your suggested signature might make more sense anyway (since you can't avoid boxing value types.)

Comment: It sure did work.  Thank you for taking the time to help me - I was running into trouble until I noticed you took one of the anonymous types away for AddUnique(TValue).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate a string to every possible key out there. You have to solution to this problem:

- use only strings as keys
- use something that is unique always e.g. URL or [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)*

It's not really unique, but the probability of a collision is near 0, especially on a single machine. [More info on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one.aspx).